# Java - Array is not printing the values I want it to

Tags: java, arrays

I'm writing a program that prints an array containing the sum of the values of two arrays passed as parameters. I need to include exceptions for when one of the arrays may be longer than the other. In that case, the method should print the sum of the indexes that both arrays share, then print the values of the array that don't have a corresponding value to add to.

When I run the program, it computes the sum as it should, but then prints 0.0 instead of the original values from the longer array that I just want re-printed. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong in my code?

```
    import java.util.*;

class Sum
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        double [] a1 = {2.4, 3.8};
        double [] a2 = {0.2, 9.2, 4.3, 2.8, 1.4};

        System.out.println (Arrays.toString (arraySum(a1,a2)));
    }

    public static double [] arraySum (double [] x, double [] y)
    {
        int length = 0;
        int place = 0;

        if (x.length < y.length)
        {
            double [] sumY = new double [y.length];
            length = y.length;

            for (int j = 0; j <= x.length-1; j++)
            {
                sumY [j] = x[j] + y[j];
                place++;
            }

            for (int i = place; i <= y.length - 1; i++)
            {
                sumY [place] = y[i];
            }       

            return sumY;        
        }

        if (x.length > y.length)
        {
            double [] sumX = new double [x.length];
            length = x.length;

            for (int j=0; j <= y.length-1; j++)
            {
                sumX[j] = x[j] + y[j];
                place++;
            }

            for (int i = place; i <= x.length - 1; i++)
            {
                sumX [place] = y[i];
            }

            return sumX;
        }

        else
        {
            double [] sum = new double [x.length];
            length = x.length;

            for (int i = 0; i <= length - 1; i++)
            {
                sum[i] = x[i] + y[i];
            }

            return sum;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is your second question about a similar topic.  How about you do your homework yourself, srsarkar7?

Answer (score 4):

Change `sumX [place] = y[i];` to `sumX [i] = y[i];`.

Comment: Also, the second loop under `if (x.length > y.length)` is copying from the wrong array.

Answer (score 1):

You are not incrementing `place` in the subsequent `for` loops.

```
for (int i = place; i <= x.length - 1; i++)
{
  sumX [place] = y[i];
  place++;
}
```

Comment: Or use SumX[i] instead of SumX[place]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - I only want place to increment in the first for loop for the first two if statements. Right?

Comment: @srsarkar7 if you don't increment `place`, you'll be assigning to `sumX[place]` over and over.  Don't you want to put something in the other array elements too?

Comment: @srsarkar7, ajb is right.. if place is not incremented, it gets overwritten and only the final value is present in it at the end...

Answer (score 0):

Your if else construction looks suspicious. It seems the last else is executed in your case but shouldn't...

Comment: Shouldn't it be like: if (x.length < y.length)
else if (x.length > y.length) else ... ?

Comment: Since there are return statements for each case, the last else won't get executed if x.length is not > y.length if that's what you're thinking.

Answer (score 0):

The whole `arraySum` method has a lot of repeated code that could be removed, which would make the method cleaner, easier to understand, and less likely to have errors.

```
public static double [] arraySum (double [] x, double [] y)
{
    int length = Math.max(d.length, y.length);

    double[] result = new double[length]; // initializes all values to 0

    for (int i=0;i<length;i++) {
       if (i<x.length)
          result[i] = x[i]; // if x is this length use its value instead of 0
       if (i<y.length)
          result[i] += y[i]; // if y is this length add its value to the sum
    }

    return result;
}
```

That's all you need...